# What are the message size limitations of stellar consensus protocol?

Tags: transactions, scp

The question is a two part question:

1. What is the message size limitation of stellar consensus protocol?
2. Also how does the message size affect the TPS of stellar?

Answer (score 2):

SCP doesn't have any theoretical limits, since really all you need to agree on is a SHA-256 hash of an arbitrary-sized set of transactions.  However, the Stellar validators vote to set a maximum number of transactions per block, which is currently at 50 transactions/block.  To see this value, you can query horizon for the latest block header:

```
$ curl 'https://horizon.stellar.org/ledgers?limit=1&order=desc'
...
        "max_tx_set_size": 50,
```